Normally closed N-channel MOS driver
I need to control high power N-channel MOSFET with ATmega328P. The lowest transistor resistance is achieved at a gate voltage of 8-10 V, just like the main VCC, so I'm thinking of using something like:

Will it work?

Switch contacts designated normally closed would conduct current in their normal state. Is that what you mean?

@RussellH I mean is that when there is a positive voltage across the base of the NPN transistor, the MOSFET will open.

In electronic, open means high resistance (infinite) as in open circuit. Closed means low (zero) resistance. I think you mean that a positive voltage is across the base-emitter junction then the FET will conduct, which it will

The BJT is wired as an emitter follower so you’re not going to get your desired gate voltage. You either need to swap the BJT and resistor positions or swap the NPN for a PNP. In either case you’ll need to invert the logic of the PWM in your code. If you don’t want to do that, then you need to add a 2nd BJT stage because each stage acts like a logic inverter.

I call this behavior "positive logic" not "normally closed".
You will want to do this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The N type transistors need to be on the ground side.  The second NPN is to invert the signal so that the logic works as you have requested.
